# Spark: computationally efficient way to compare dates?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge data set which needs to be filtered by date (dates are stored as yyyy-MM-dd format). Which of the following options is the most computationally efficient way to do that (and why)?

`df.filter("unix_timestamp(dt_column,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= unix_timestamp('2017-02-03','yyyy-MM-dd')")`

OR

`df.filter("cast(dt_column as date) >= cast('2017-02-03' as date)")`

Comment: there should no significant difference in performance characteristics of both queries..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `dt_column` is already in `yyyy-MM-dd` no need to `cast`/`unix_timestamp` it again. [**Internally spark does lexicographic comparison with Strings only for all date types**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/TypeCoercion.scala#L317-L327) (As of Spark 2.1). There won't be any `date` type at low level when comparison happens.

Now `cast('2017-02-03' as date)` and `unix_timestamp('2017-02-03','yyyy-MM-dd')` may not cause performance issue as it's constant. **I'd recommand you to use DataSet functions to catch syntax issues at compile time**

```
//These two should be the same
df.filter(df("dt_column") >= lit("2017-02-03"))

df.filter(df("dt_column") >= lit("2017-02-03").cast(DataTypes.DateType))
```

> `cast` and `unix_timestamp` both generates dates from strings but
>   `unix_timestamp` gives options to create date in diff formats. Apart
>   from that, **there shouldn't be any diff in terms of performance**.

Comment: for spark 3.0+ , this has changed.

`Since Spark 3.0, Spark will cast String to Date/TimeStamp in binary comparisons with dates/timestamps. The previous behaviour of casting Date/Timestamp to String can be restored by setting spark.sql.legacy.typeCoercion.datetimeToString to true.`